# jQuery parse xml into nested list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, html-lists

I have some xml from a webservice that I would like to parse and create a nested unordered list so that I can style using CSS to make it look like a treeview.
The xml is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfNavMenuItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <NavMenuItem>
        <DOMAIN_USERNAME>SomeUser</DOMAIN_USERNAME>
        <PRIMARY_FOLDER>XYZ HR EMP SELF SERVICE</PRIMARY_FOLDER>
        <MENU_DISPLAY_NAME>Accommodation Request</MENU_DISPLAY_NAME>
    </NavMenuItem>
    <NavMenuItem>
        <DOMAIN_USERNAME>SomeUser</DOMAIN_USERNAME>
        <PRIMARY_FOLDER>XYZ HR EMP SELF SERVICE</PRIMARY_FOLDER>
        <MENU_DISPLAY_NAME>Additional Personal Information</MENU_DISPLAY_NAME>
    </NavMenuItem>
    <NavMenuItem>
        <DOMAIN_USERNAME>SomeUser</DOMAIN_USERNAME>
        <PRIMARY_FOLDER>XYZ HR EMP SELF SERVICE</PRIMARY_FOLDER>
        <MENU_DISPLAY_NAME>All Actions Awaiting Your Attention</MENU_DISPLAY_NAME>
    </NavMenuItem>
    <NavMenuItem>
        <DOMAIN_USERNAME>SomeUser</DOMAIN_USERNAME>
        <PRIMARY_FOLDER>XYZ CORP HR TIME SELF SERVICE</PRIMARY_FOLDER>
        <SECONDARY_FOLDER>Time</SECONDARY_FOLDER>
        <MENU_DISPLAY_NAME>Create Timecard</MENU_DISPLAY_NAME>
    </NavMenuItem>
    <NavMenuItem>
        <DOMAIN_USERNAME>SomeUser</DOMAIN_USERNAME>
        <PRIMARY_FOLDER>XYZ CORP HR TIME SELF SERVICE</PRIMARY_FOLDER>
        <SECONDARY_FOLDER>Time</SECONDARY_FOLDER>
        <MENU_DISPLAY_NAME>Recent Timecards</MENU_DISPLAY_NAME>
    </NavMenuItem>
    <NavMenuItem>
        <DOMAIN_USERNAME>SomeUser</DOMAIN_USERNAME>
        <PRIMARY_FOLDER>XYZ CORP HR TIME SELF SERVICE</PRIMARY_FOLDER>
        <SECONDARY_FOLDER>Time</SECONDARY_FOLDER>
        <MENU_DISPLAY_NAME>Timecard Search</MENU_DISPLAY_NAME>
    </NavMenuItem>
</ArrayOfNavMenuItem>
```

and my poor man's attempt at jQuery is so far. I am not sure how I can capture primary folder, secondary folder structure before I iterate over each nav item and add them to `<li></li>` inside of the appropriate folders

[My fiddle is here..](http://jsbin.com/zukawifegu/edit?html,js,output)

```
//AJAX CALL
$(response).find('NavMenuItem').each(function (index) {
var test = ($(this).find('SECONDARY_FOLDER').length > 0) ? '<ul><li><label for="subfolder' + index +'">' + $(this).find("SECONDARY_FOLDER").text() + '</label><input type="checkbox" id="subfolder' + index + '">' : '';            
$('.SearchResults').append('<ul class="tree"><li><label for="folder' + index + '">' + $(this).find("PRIMARY_FOLDER").text() + '</label>'
  + '<input type="checkbox" checked id="folder' + index + '" />'
  + test
  + '<ul><li class="file"><a href="#">' + $(this).find("MENU_DISPLAY_NAME").text() + '</a></li></ul>'       
  + '</li></ul>');             
});
```

But my desired HTML output is something like this:

```
    <ul class="tree">
        <li>
          <label for="folder1">XYZ CORP HR TIME SELF SERVICE </label> 
          <input type="checkbox" checked id="folder1" />   
            <ul>
                <li><label for="subfolder1">Time</label> <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder1" />

                        <ul>
                            <li class="file"><a href="#" target="_tab">Create Timecard</a></li>
                            <li class="file"><a href="#" target="_tab">Recent Timecards</a></li>
                            <li class="file"><a href="#" target="_tab">Timecard Search</a></li>                                   
                        </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>        
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="folder2">XYZ HR EMP SELF SERVICE</label> <input type="checkbox"  id="folder2" />                
            <ul>
                <li class="file"><a href="#" target="_tab">Accommodation Request</a></li>
                <li class="file"><a href="#" target="_tab">Additional Personal Information</a></li>
                <li class="file"><a href="#" target="_tab">All Actions Awaiting Your Attention</a></li>           
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: My problem here is that I was originally building this solution by transforming xml using XSLT so I had a way to template and return call whenever there is a match, hence effectively creating groupings based on matches. I am having difficulty emulating that template match kind of behavior in jQuery. But now I can't use XSLT. It has to be all jQuery/JavaScript/CSS solution on the client side

Comment: I will write the code for it, but have you checked this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578154/can-you-use-jquery-to-transfrom-xml-to-xml-via-xslt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
var tree=$('<ul></ul>').addClass('tree'); // create an unordered list with the class 'tree'
$('NavMenuItem',response).each(function() { //for each item in NavMenuItem
    var primary=$('PRIMARY_FOLDER',this).text(); //get the text of the PRIMARY_FOLDER element
    var secondary=$('SECONDARY_FOLDER',this).text();
    var displayName=$('MENU_DISPLAY_NAME',this).text();
    if (!primary) return; // this shouldn't happen, but still, if no primary folder, ignore it
    //search for a direct listitem that has a direct child a label
    // that has the primary text as content (get the label, then return its parent)
    var li=$('>li>label:contains("'+primary+'"):first',tree).parent();
    if (!li.length) { // if not found, create it
        var index=$('>li',tree).length+1; // the number of list items in the tree plus 1
        var li=$('<li></li>') // create a list item
            .append($('<label for="folder'+index+'"></label>').text(primary)) //that contains a label
            .append('<input type="checkbox" checked id="folder'+index+'" />') // and an input
            .append('<ul></ul>'); // and an unordered list
        tree.append(li); //add it to the tree
    }
    if (secondary) { //if we have a secondary folder
        var ul = $('>ul',li); // find the unordered list in it
        // same as with primary, only here
        var li2=$('>li>label:contains("'+secondary+'"):first',ul).parent();
        if (!li2.length) {
            var index=$('>li',ul).length+1;
            var li2=$('<li></li>')
                .append($('<label for="subfolder'+index+'"></label>').text(secondary))
                .append('<input type="checkbox" checked id="subfolder'+index+'" />')
                .append('<ul></ul>')
            ul.append(li2);
        }
        li=li2; //set the current listitem to be the secondary
    }
    var ul = $('>ul',li); //get the unordered list child of the current listitem
    var index=$('>li',ul).length+1; //compute file index (if you need it)
    //add the file
    ul.append($('<li></li>').addClass('file').append($('<a href="#" target="_tab"></a>').text(displayName)));
});
// add the tree to the element with class 'SearchResults'
$('.SearchResults').append(tree);
```

I did it as jQuery as possible, although my opinion is that you should create a javascript structure that has everything grouped, then transform it to jQuery DOM manipulation.

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I needed. This is advanced stuff for me, so currently studying your code. Thanks very much!

Comment: I updated the code with comments. I again stress that this is not perfect or performant code, it is just for learning purposes. The best code would repeat the same algorithm in a data structure, then dumbly just create the tree afterwards. Also some weird names of folders might mess the :contains selector. This code has the advantage that you could add items to an existing tree in the page just by running the function on a NavItem

Answer (score 1):

It seems your problem is that you want to add am unordered list to the element with the class SearchResults, and then add a list item to the list for each element of the XML, instead you are adding an unordered list for each element. First step is to fix that:

```
var tree=$('<ul class="tree"></ul>').appendTo('.SearchResults');
$(response).find('NavMenuItem').each(function (index) {
    var test = ($(this).find('SECONDARY_FOLDER').length > 0) 
        ? '<ul><li><label for="subfolder' + index + '">' + $(this).find("SECONDARY_FOLDER").text() + '</label><input type="checkbox" id="subfolder' + index + '">' 
        : '';
    tree.append('<li><label for="folder' + index + '">' + $(this).find("PRIMARY_FOLDER").text() + '</label>'
         + '<input type="checkbox" checked id="folder' + index + '" />'
         + test
         + '<ul><li class="file"><a href="#">' + $(this).find("MENU_DISPLAY_NAME").text() + '</a></li></ul>'
         + '</li>');
});
```

Then some observations:

- `$(this).find('SECONDARY_FOLDER')` is the same as
  `$('SECONDARY_FOLDER',this)`
- `if (X>0)` is the same as `if (X)`
- JQuery has a nice way of chaining methods, so you can append items as
  you are adding them like `$('<li></li').append($('<input
  />').css({display:'none'}).val(someValue))`, etc. which might make
  your code more readable and thus maintainable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not just adding each element in the XML to the SearchResults div, I am also needing to group the elements based on the primary folder values, and secondary folder values. if you look at the desired html output, you will see what I am talking about..